# Artifactory newGradleBuild() - artifactoryDeploy .zip' does not exists, and need to be published

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I have a spring boot application where i need to created boot.tar file and i need to exclude all the files created by gradle application plugin

```
apply plugin: 'war'

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.6')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.6')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.6')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')

}
apply plugin: 'application'
application {
    mainClassName = 'com.xx.MyMainClass'
}

distZip.enabled = false
distTar.enabled = false
bootDistZip.enabled = false
```

I also have a generic jenkins pipeline which run the gradle build using `jenkins artifactory plugin` when i ran the build it failed with the following error

```
Execution failed for task artifactoryDeploy 
File '/workerfs/workspace/mybuild/2/myApp/build/distributions/myapp-x.y.z.zip' does not exists, and need to be published!.zip' does not exists, and need to be published
```

**Updated Jenkinsfile**

```
rtGradle = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
rtGradle.usesPlugin = false
rtGradle.deployer.deployMavenDescriptors = true
rtGradle.deployer.deployIvyDescriptors= false
rtGradle.deployer server: server, repo: "snapshotLocal"
rtGradle.resolver server: "myartifactoryserver", repo: "virtualLocal"
rtGradle.useWrapper = true
rtGradle.deployer.deployArtifacts = false

               rtGradle.run rootDir: ".", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: "clean build artifactoryPublish", buildInfo : <buidINfoObj>
```

Comment: Can you show your build.gradle? Somehow the configuration doesn't show enough information to say what's the issue. Looks like the plug-in wants to deploy a zip, but from the code snippet it's deactivated.

Comment: added complete build.gradle

Comment: We also use artifactory. But we use the Gradle plugin to publish it. So I have to guess what it is. Which artifactory version are you using and which version of the Jenkins plugin. Then I'll try to reproduce it in our environment.

Comment: For the beginning could you try to build once with and once without enable distzip, build it locally and check the folder structure if it is similar to the expecting folder given in the error message. Further check the documentation if there are options to set for the jenkins artifactory plugin. Especially if it is expecting a zip file. Think it's kinda configuration. Looks like it's expecting a specific file, which is not yours, right?

Comment: Could you also add your jenkins pipeline part? Without endpoint and credentials of course.

Comment: we are using artifactory plugin version 3.3.2, also updated the jenkins file call